# Regex helped needed for angular filter which highlights matching text from html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs

I have this which works but but the regex is matching with html tags, is there any way I could get it to ignore html tags. Could anyone help me to modify the regex expression so my class is only applied to text and not matching html tags?

```
angular.module('my.filters')
    .filter('highlight', function ($sce) {
        return function (text, filterPhrase) {
            if (filterPhrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + filterPhrase + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="quick-find-highlight">$1</span>');
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your regular expression (filterPhrase)?

Comment: It will just be a text string which the user will type in, works sort of like Ctrl + f in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code, where I split by tags and replace only when string is not a tag.

```
angular.module('my.filters')
    .filter('highlight', function($sce) {
        return function(text, filterPhrase) {
            if (filterPhrase) {
                var tag_re = /(<\/?[^>]+>)/g;
                var filter_re = new RegExp('(' + filterPhrase + ')', 'gi');
                text = text.split(tag_re).map(function(string) {
                    if (string.match(tag_re)) {
                        return string;
                    } else {
                        return string.replace(filter_re, 
                                              '<span class="quick-find-highlight">$1</span>');
                    }
                }).join('');
            }
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    });
```